# x86 Assembly Programming (GAS Syntax): How to get the nth bit of a variable stored in a register

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-manipulation, att

I am trying to get the 5th bit of a variable stored in the EDX register (Intel x86 Assembly using GAS or AT&T syntax) and move it to the ESI register. However, when I execute my program, I get the following error:

> /tmp/SASM/program.asm:54: Error: found '$', expected: ')'
>
> /tmp/SASM/program.asm:54: Error: junk `$5,%edx)' after expression

Below is my code:

```
mov (shl $5, %edx), %esi
```

Comment: You can't combine random instructions like that to create addressing modes. You'll need at least 2 instructions to do it.

Comment: What content is `esi` supposed to have afterwards?  Perhaps try `mov %edx, %esi; and $1<<5, %esi`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use more than instruction to check if the 5th bit is set. But you have several possiblities to check this condition (the list is far from being complete):

1. First variant

   ```
    xorl  %esi , %esi   ; set ESI to 0
    shrl  $5   , %edx   ; shift 5 bits right into CARRY
    setc  %sil          ; set lowest bit of ESI if CARRY is set
   ```
2. Second variant

   ```
    xorl  %esi , %esi   ; set ESI to 0
    shrl  $5   , %edx   ; shift 5 bits right in to CARRY
    rcll  $1   , %esi   ; rotate CARRY flag into lowest bit of ESI
   ```
3. Third variant

   ```
    xorl   %esi, %esi   ; set ESI to 0
    testl  $16 , %edx   ; AND operation of 16 decimal and ESI - check if the 5th bit is set
    setnz  %sil         ; set the lowest bit of ESI if the TEST operation doesn't set the ZERO flag
   ```
4. There are many more possibilities whose usefulness depend on the surrounding code...

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation :D. Would you mind explaining how "rcll $1, %esi" puts the value of the edx register shifted 5 bits to the right into the esi register? I'm confused as to what you mean by "rotate CARRY flag into the lowest bit of ESI".

Comment: This is explained in the [3rd paragraph of the description of RCL](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rcl:rcr:rol:ror). ROL rotates the bits in a register, and RCL includes the carry flag in the rotation.